# Angular RxJS create timer loop based on varying duration in the objects of an array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

The scenario I'm trying here is to read the data, loop based on the duration, so for example, take "Adam" first, play Adam for 15 seconds timer then go to the next beginner "Andy", play Andy for 15 seconds.

Because "play" is 1, move to the next group "intermediate", play "Fam" for 30s then move to "Jamie" & play for 30s.. once done, loop intermediate because "play" is 2... Once complete, move to "expert"

```
let data = [{
    "play": 1,
    "name": "Adam",
    "duration": 15,
    "group": "beginner"
}, {
    "play": 1,
    "group": "beginner",
    "name": "Andy",
    "duration": 15
}, {
    "duration": 30,
    "play": 2,
    "name": "Fam",
    "group": "intermediate"
}, {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "group": "intermediate",
    "duration": 30,
    "play": 2
},
{
    "duration": 45,
    "play": 2,
    "name": "Fam",
    "group": "expert"
}, {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "group": "expert",
    "duration": 45,
    "play": 2
}];
```

```js
destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
onStart() {
  from(data).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    concatMap(record => timer(0, record.duration * 1000).pipe(
    map(i => data[i]))
  ))
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.currentItem = data;
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
  this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Huge thanks for sharing your idea in advance
Thanks!

Comment: Please be more clear on your question. what is your problem? what wrong with your current solution?

Comment: The current solution does not change the timer, for example, the timer is meant to change from 15s to 30s when the data changes from beginner to intermediate.. however, the current solution only uses one timer 15s or 30s throughout the map loop

Answer (score 1):

What you have is almost correct. When you use `timer` with two parameters it has different meaning than with just one:

- `timer(0, 15)` will emit right on subscription and then every `15ms` forever (it never completes, `concatMap` will never subscribe to the next record...).
- `timer(15)` will emit just once after `15ms` and then complete.

So you should use for example the following:

```
concatMap(record => timer(record.duration * 1000).pipe(
  map(() => record),
),
```

Or you can use `delay()`.

```
concatMap(record => of(record).pipe(
  delay(record.duration * 1000),
),
```

Comment: Hi @martin, timer(15) doesn't start immediately. It waits for 15s before it starts the first process & this occurs for the rest of the objects.. this is the reason why I used timer(0, 15).. Is there any way of triggering timer(15) to start immediately instead of wait 15s?? Thanks

Comment: So you want it to emit twice. Frist at `0` and then at `15s`? In that case you'll have to use `take(2)` to force complete the chain `timer(0, record.duration * 1000).pipe(map(() => record ), take(2))`. I'm not sure about this either `map(i => data[i])` because this is going to use only the first two records from `data`.

Comment: yea using take(2) will only take the first 2 objects in data.. it basically needs to emit at 0, take the first object in the array & delay it for the duration in that object i.e. 15s

then emit the next object & delay it for its duration e.t.c

Comment: so what I suggested should be doing what you want. Otherwise, could you make a stackblitz demo showing what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is:  concatMap(item => timer(record.duration * 1000).pipe(ignoreElements(), startWith(record)))

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
import { from, timer, of } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, repeat, delayWhen, scan, mapTo, concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";

interface Item {
  play: number;
  name: string;
  duration: number,
  group: string;
}

let data: Item[] = [{
    "play": 1,
    "name": "Adam",
    "duration": 15,
    "group": "beginner"
}, {
    "play": 1,
    "group": "beginner",
    "name": "Andy",
    "duration": 15
}, {
    "duration": 30,
    "play": 2,
    "name": "Fam",
    "group": "intermediate"
}, {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "group": "intermediate",
    "duration": 30,
    "play": 2
},
{
    "duration": 45,
    "play": 2,
    "name": "Fam",
    "group": "expert"
}, {
    "name": "Dan",
    "group": "expert",
    "duration": 45,
    "play": 2
}];

createQueue(data)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });

function createQueue(data: Item[]) {
// implement 'repeat' logic
  const dataWithDublicates = data
    .reduce((acc, item) => [ ...acc, ...new Array(item.play).fill(item)], []);
// calculate delay on next item based on prev item
  const dataWithDelaysAndRepeats = dataWithDublicates.map(
    (element, index) => ({ 
      element, 
      delay: dataWithDublicates[index-1] ? dataWithDublicates[index-1].duration : 0 
    }))

  return from(dataWithDelaysAndRepeats).pipe(
    concatMap(({element, delay}) => timer(delay * 100)
      .pipe(mapTo(element))
    )
  );
}
```

There is working demo (look at browser console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4qu5r6?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Hey @izmaylovdev, thanks for trying this out.. this is more what I wanted not the above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777105/angular-rxjs-timer